# Installed latest version of Python in Anaconda prompt but no reflect in Spyder

Tags: python

Installed the latest version `Python 3.10.6` in Anaconda prompt but the version is not reflect in the Spyder. It still reflect `Python 3.8.8` in Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda hasn't added Python 3.10.6 yet.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files
conda install -c conda-forge python (main: 3.10.5)

1. https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html
2. https://github.com/winpython/winpython/releases (Winpython64-3.10.5.0.exe)
3. https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution
4. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder (main: Spyder 5.3.2)

Note: Usually installed on "base" without any problems. It may cause problems in other environments.

conda activate base

conda install -c conda-forge spyder

Note: If there are inconsistent packages while installing the base, you will either remove these packages or add a new environment. Your advice is to set up in a new environment. Then it will install without problems.

Comment: Which file need to download and how to install it in order to reflect in the spyder? Will the new version reflect in spyder if  download the `python 3.10.5` from the python website?

Comment: Note: Usually installed on "base" without any problems. It may cause problems in other environments.

conda activate base

conda install -c conda-forge spyder

Note: If there are inconsistent packages while installing the base, you will either remove these packages or add a new environment. Your advice is to set up in a new environment. Then it will install without problems.